# CakePHP - Controller without View & Model

Tags: cakephp

How do I create a controller with no view and model?
Making a services_controller to spit out json.

This is what I have now.

```
var $uses = array();

function test() {
    $this->autoRender = false;
    echo "test";
}
```

However, that doesn't print out the "test" message.

Thanks,
Tee

Comment: The most correct way these days would be to use `.json` extension URLs and use Json (or Ajax) View to properly return json encoded data the "cake way".

Answer (score 4):

The above code actually works. The issue was somewhere else related to the Auth component.

Thanks,
Tee

Answer (score 3):

Just write  $this->autoRender = false; at the end of the function. It will surely work.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Novarg: I don't see why Devendra's post would not qualify as an answer but just a comment. It's not very verbose but it does try to answer the Question.

Answer (score 0):

I know that using the statement below your controller is without reference to any model:

```
public $ uses = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->autoRender = false;
```

This one works like a die() function. Put it at the end of the function.